# downside(s) of jQuery vs 4 other Libs

Tags: jquery, dojo, mootools, yui, google-closure-library

I am very specific here not asking about jQuery vs Javascript or something non-sense like this.

I have spent more than a month to learn jQuery (yes I am bit slow) and I have found it very useful but a friend of mine has suggested me 4 other libraries too names as:

1. Google's closure library
2. Mootools
3. YUI Library
4. Dojo

But I don't want to spend six months more to learn these fours and then realize which one is more useful compared with jQuery and dig more into it.

So, I am here and I am sure somebody will be able to help me to know what if any downside(s) are of jQuery vs these four libraries and what are plus points of these libraries compared with jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

Comment: Use jQuery. Find your pain points. Search for solutions in other libraries or roll your own.

Comment: Don't use a library for the reason of using a library. Only use a library when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

This is largely a matter of personal taste.

I've played with some of these. jQuery has one of the nicest APIs to use, but you occasionally pay for this with performance (although probably only compared to raw code; I doubt the others will be better here).

jQuery seems to be the most actively developed of the bunch, and seems to be very reliable.

In Dojo I've seen some of the crappies JavaScript code in my life, so that library is a no-go for me by now.

Google closure library is a bit tricky to use, but actually very cool. But I'd only use it when also using the closure compiler, which does a good job at optimizing and minimizing Code. This is when the library actually plays its strengths.

Anyway, **you'll have to try them yourself** and see which style you like best. **It is a matter of taste**, and we can't help you with that.

Comment: crappiest code in dojo? I admit loading modules etc. is a bit messy, but in general it doesn't look any worse than other library. I think all of them are ugly, especially with the ({ }); start and end.

Comment: No, more like a slow, ten-line code, that could be replaced with a simple modulo operation. They really need to pay attention to code quality.